# How to load a file with different names with SQL Loader?

Tags: sql, batch-file, csv

My problem is that I would like to load a file data (.csv) into Oracle table with SQL Loader but the file name changes all days.

e.g : I have this .csv file today *TEST06062014.csv* and here is the code

```
INFILE 'TEST06062014.csv'
```

It works well.

But I'm going to use this everyday and so the file name changes (tommorrow, the file name will be *TEST07062014.csv*)

Could I replace the file name by "*" character or an other solution?
Have you an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing a batch script and then schedule it to run everyday with date as a parameter. In case you are confused how to get date in DDMMYYYY format, you can have a look at this link:
http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/956/windows-batch-file-bat-to-get-current-date-in-mmddyyyy-format/

Comment: I want to know if it isn't possible to use wildcard?